# printing a "toast" message on the first app after returning from the second app

Tags: android, toast

I am trying to so the following on android studio :
Sending the user to another app (i.e a second app like Facebook or or Twitter ) from my android app that I developed.then , if the user closes the second app, I need to go back to the first app (i.e my app) and show a "toast message " on it.

After some search, I have found some way of sending the user from my app to the second app if the user a presses a button on my app.

However, I did not know how to print a "a toast message " if the user closes the second ?

Any help would be really apprecaitd

Answer (score 0):

There is a activity lifecycle callback called `onResume()` ( `onStart()` also works), this callback is called when the user comes back to your app, so you can make a toast message in this method

```
void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    Toast.makeText(...).show();
}
```

But this method is also called when the app starts, so maybe you need a boolean flag to distinguish those situations

```
void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    if(isBack){
        Toast.makeText(...).show();
        isBack = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html#onresume   this is useful

Comment: BTW, what if i have an  android service that is running a server  on my android app and continuously listening to any message request from a client. if the server receives a message from the client (i.e ringdoor), then the app will go from the android service to a short activity (blue screen with "accept" and "decline button" that lasts for 15 secs ) .

Comment: then, if the user presses "accept", then the user will go from this short activity  to the second app (i.e foscam). please note that after it goes to the second the app, the short activity is finished using the finish( method). my question: will the "on resume method" still work to show a toast message on my app?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ChsVxI-iucY&feature=youtu.be  the video shows my app

Comment: If the activity is destroyed, the method is definitely NOT gonna work

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use `startActivityForResult` when you start second activity. Then in `onActivityResult`, you can do whatever you want (eg: show `Toast message`) when second activity finish.

Assume first activity class is called `FirstActivity`, & second activity is `SecondActivity`.

In `FirstActivity`, do this when you want to start `SecondActivity`:

```
// use "startActivityForResult" instaed of "startActivity"
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, "START_SECOND_ACTIVITY");
```

To detect finish of `second activity`, add this in `first activity`:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == "START_SECOND_ACTIVITY") {
        // show Toast message
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "SecondActivity finish", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW, what if i have an android service that is running a server on my android app and continuously listening to any message request from a client. if the server receives a message from the client (i.e ringdoor), then the app will go from the android service to a short activity (blue screen with "accept" and "decline button" that lasts for 15 secs

Comment: then, if the user presses "accept", then the user will go from this short activity to the second app (i.e foscam). please note that after it goes to the second the app, the short activity is finished using the finish( method). my question: will the "onresume" method still work to show a toast message on my app? –

Comment: youtube.com/watch?v=ChsVxI-iucY&feature=youtu.be the video shows my app

Comment: My code doesn't involve doing anything in `onResume` though.